# Avoiding pre-opened popups in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers

I'm using Leaflet to show some info for points:

```
var m1 = L.marker([20, 90], {icon: picture}).addTo(mymap);
m1.bindPopup('<h1 class="center">Caption</h1> <br><b>Info: </b>bla').openPopup();
```

How can you avoid that one popup is always opened when opening the HTML document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply remove the call of `.openPopup()` on your marker:

```
var m1 = L.marker([20, 90], {icon: picture}).addTo(mymap);
m1.bindPopup('<h1 class="center">Caption</h1> <br><b>Info: </b>bla');
```